# LUIS - can I define the timestamp of the message being sent to the API?

Tags: nlp, azure-language-understanding

Our English LUIS model provides correctly values of entity `builtin.datetimeV2` for relative time like:

> *"an hour ago"*

Sometimes it happens that even several days old message is being sent to LUIS API. Is there a way how to specify the original timestamp of such message when sending request to get correct time from the result?

I see that current situation is possible to be handled partially at the client. It can compare "original timestamp" of input message and "actual time" and use the difference to shift the result value if my program detects that the value of `builtin.datetimeV2` was relative. I see this solution as error prone due to the necessity of detection of "relative time" in the client.

---

Example of result from message "an hour ago":

```
"entities": [
    {
      "entity": "an hour ago",
      "type": "builtin.datetimeV2.datetime",
      "startIndex": 48,
      "endIndex": 58,
      "resolution": {
        "values": [
          {
            "timex": "2018-04-06T13:33:15",
            "type": "datetime",
            "value": "2018-04-06 13:33:15"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The endpoint querystring takes a [timezoneOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-concept-data-alteration#endpoint-querystring-parameter) which should allow you to alter the time. It isn't meant for your specific case but it might work.